# How to trucate the encripted array to size 16 in AES encreption in java

Tags: java, aes, encryption

> i want to encript a byte array following is mycode  it works fine but
>   gives an output newByteArray of long size i want outputed array should
>   be of size 16 is it possible

```
 byte [] keyForEncription= new byte[16];
        byte [] keyForDecription= new byte[16];
        long  FixedKey= 81985526925837671L;
        long  VariableKey=744818830;
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 8; i1++)
        {

            keyForEncription[i1] = (byte)(FixedKey >> (8 * i1));
            keyForEncription[i1 + 8] = (byte)(VariableKey >> (8 * i1));
        }


    byte[] data = new byte[255];

    data[0]= 2;
    data[1]= 0;
    data[2]= 0;
    data[3]= 0;
    data[4]= 0;
    data[5]= 6;
    data[6]= 6;
    data[7]= 81;
    data[8]= 124;
    data[9]= 123;
    data[10]= 123;
    data[11]= 12;
    data[12]= 3;
    data[13]= 27;
    data[15]= 12;
    data[16]= 0;
    data[17]= 0;
    data[18]= 0;
    data[19]= 0;

    System.out.println("Original byte Array : " +Arrays.toString(data));

    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyForEncription, "AES");
   Cipher cipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] newByteArray = new byte[data.length];
    newByteArray = cipher.doFinal(byteArray);
    System.out.println("Encrypted Array : " +Arrays.toString(newByteArray));
```

> here is the output Encrypted Array : [110, -118, -119, -88, 73, -118,
>   57, 15, -52, -78, 100, 104, 102, -42, -102, -45, -50, -116, -47, -53,
>   103, -40, -61, 62, 42, 15, -124, 98, -28, -77, 94, 78, -50, -116, -47,
>   -53, 103, -40, -61, 62, 42, 15, -124, 98, -28, -77, 94, 78, -50, -116, -47, -53, 103, -40, -61, 62, 42, 15, -124, 98, -28, -77, 94, 78, -50, -116, -47, -53, 103, -40, -61, 62, 42, 15, -124, 98, -28, -77, 94, 78, -50, -116, -47, -53, 103, -40, -61, 62, 42, 15, -124, 98, -28, -77, 94, 78]

Comment: ECB of CFB? Your question says ECB, and your code says CFB.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works fine here:

```
    byte[] key = new byte[16];
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

    byte[] data = "hello world.....".getBytes();
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(data);
    System.out.println("Encrypted Array : " + Arrays.toString(encrypted));
```

It won't work with `"hello world".getBytes()` though, since the input size is not a multiple of 16:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length not multiple of 16 bytes
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:854)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:828)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2086)
    at com.foo.bar.CryptoTest.main(CryptoTest.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Bute that's expected, since no padding is used. If that's the exception you get (and not "invalide key" as your question says), then fix the length of your input data. Else, paste the exact and complete error stack trace in your question.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length not multiple of 16 bytes
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:853)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:827)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:675)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
 at EncriptTest.main(EncriptTest.java:66)

Comment: Then you know what to do. It's the exact same exception as the one in my answer, and I explained you why you get it and how not to get it. The message of the exception says it all, BTW. Note that it says "Input length" and not "Key length".

Comment: change the length of input data to multiple of 16 and the problem is solved thanks